# web page does not get loaded from docker container

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I can't access Sequence-server ( http://localhost:4567 ) in the browser after I did the following steps:

```
$ wget -c https://github.com/wurmlab/sequenceserver/archive/refs/tags/2.0.0.tar.gz
$ vim docker-compose.yml
$ cat docker-compose.yml 
sequenceserver:
  build: sequenceserver-2.0.0
  restart: always
  ports:
    - "4567:4567"
  volumes:
    - ./data/sequenceserver:/db
```

```
$ docker-compose build
...
Installing slop 3.6.0
Using sequenceserver 2.0.0 (was 2.0.0.rc8) from source at `.`
`/sequenceserver/bin/sequenceserver` does not exist, maybe `gem pristine sequenceserver` will fix it?
Bundle complete! 8 Gemfile dependencies, 11 gems now installed.
Gems in the group development were not installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
...
Get:16 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libgomp1 amd64 8.3.0-6 [75.8 kB]
Get:17 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 liblmdb0 amd64 0.9.22-1 [45.0 kB]
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Fetched 2278 kB in 0s (12.2 MB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package libkeyutils1:amd64.
(Reading database ... 8611 files and directories currently installed.)
...
Step 38/45 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in dd5eeabde4c3
npm WARN deprecated @stylelint/postcss-markdown@0.36.2: Use the original unforked package instead: postcss-markdown
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<3.4 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.4 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.4 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.

added 744 packages, and audited 745 packages in 49s
...
Run `npm audit` for details.
npm notice 
npm notice New major version of npm available! 7.7.6 -> 8.6.0
npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v8.6.0>
npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@8.6.0` to update!
npm notice 
Removing intermediate container dd5eeabde4c3
...
```

```
$ sudo docker-compose up
Creating portal_sequenceserver_1 ... done
Attaching to portal_sequenceserver_1
sequenceserver_1  | stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device
sequenceserver_1  | [2022-04-06 05:40:16] INFO  Reading configuration file: /root/.sequenceserver.conf.
```

What did I miss?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Does your application listen on 4567?

Comment: Are you using docker in WSL?

Comment: @Saeed: According to the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/wurmlab/sequenceserver/blob/master/Dockerfile#L55) it does listen to 4567.

Comment: @felunka: I use docker under Debian/Linux.

Comment: I mean run `docker exec -it sequenceserver curl localhost:4567` to see if it works

Answer (score 0):

Check if your firewall blocks the port. To test it you can telnet the port from the machine you want to see the web.

Comment: How can I do it under debian?

Comment: use this command
telnet <your_server_ip_address> 4567

Comment: `telnet 127.0.0.1 4567` and `telnet 0.0.0.0 4567` gave: 
```
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```
What did I miss?